# How to Handle Two Jobs in MVC at same time

Tags: asp.net, email, wait, daypilot

Hi my current project is calendar schedule. If i move time slot box in calendar,  then called **DayPilotCalendarWeek_EventMove** and Time slate is moved successfully without Email functionality. But If i called Email Process it take some mints for mail. How to handle this Jobs???. I refer  threading concept But I cannot Understand.[**Click Here for Screen shot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ARW.png)

**Requirement is**

1. Job 1 : DayPilotCalendarWeek.Update(); // must done before sending Email.
2. After Update calender, Email functionality must work.

**MY Code is :**

Same Function two action 
1.DayPilotCalendarWeek.Update(); 
2.SendEmail();

```
protected void DayPilotCalendarWeek_EventMove(object sender, DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CommonCls com = new CommonCls();
        //**Job 1:**
        DayPilotCalendarWeek.DataSource = Moving(e.Id, e.OldStart.ToString(), e.NewStart.ToString());
        DayPilotCalendarWeek.DataBind();
        DayPilotCalendarWeek.Update();
        //**Job 2** 
        SendEmail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Asynchronous two job in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016236/how-to-asynchronous-two-job-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know ASP.NET very well but i found this:

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH","10;URL=test.aspx");.
```

This should refresh the code after 10 secons. Maybe that will work.

Comment: And what language are you useing or whith what are your working. We need information!

Comment: No must run both on same time. but terminate code  when DayPilotCalendarWeek.Update();  is done.. After that background process going to achieve email functionality.

Comment: ASP.net with C# Lanuage

Comment: Hi your understood wrongly.. This function is doing 2 jobs... first job is Update moved slot to calender that is DayPilotCalendarWeek.Update();. And second job is Email. My problem is 2 job took long time. I need to done first job quickly. Second job sending Email must do later.