# How to Asynchronous two job in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

Net. I need your favour Please help me. See my Code..
If My First job is finished then exit from **btn_ok** code behind and update to ASP.NET screen, but at the same time Job 2 must working (**Bulk Email is processing**)

```
protected void btn_ok(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

try

  { 

   //**Job 1:**

   CommonCls com = new CommonCls();
   com.SaveRecord(**Parameter Values**);

   //Note :after save this, it must exit from this function and update Message to web Application Screen 

  //**Job 2** 
   EmailDAL em = new EmailDAL();
   .....
   .....

    try {
                    em.SendEmail(PTEmail, "Appointment Rescheduled ", "Dear " + PTName + "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Appointment with " + PName + " referred by " + GPName + "  has been rescheduled " + Stime + ". <br> with Regards <br> <b>" + GPName + "</b>" + axolbl);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex.ToString()); }
                try
                {
                    em.SendEmail(PEmail, "Appointment Rescheduled ", "Dear " + PName + "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Appointment for  " + PTName + "(" + PTCode + ")  referred by " + GPName + " has been rescheduled " + Stime + ".  <br> with Regards <br> <b>" + GPName + "</b>" + axolbl);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex.ToString()); }
                try
                {
                    em.SendEmail(GPEmail, "Appointment Rescheduled ", "Dear " + GPName + "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Appointment for " + PTName + "(" + PTCode + ")  with " + PName + "  has been rescheduled " + Stime + ". <br> with Regards <br>  " + axolbl);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex.ToString()); }   
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { }
 }

 catch (Exception ex)
 { }
 }
```

Email Data Access Layer

---

```
public class EmailDAL
{

    internal string SMTP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
    internal string MailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUser"];
    internal string Pwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPass"];
    internal int Port = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);
    internal bool ssl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);

    public string SendEmail(string toMail, string mailSubject, string Message)
    {

        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(SMTP);
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(MailAddress);
        mail.To.Add(toMail);
        mail.Subject = mailSubject;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true; 
        mail.Body = "<p style='line-height: 30px;'>" + Message + "</p>";
        SmtpServer.Port =  Port;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailAddress, Pwd);
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = ssl;
        try
        {
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return "Send Sucessfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem at all. Please mark as an answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Answer
After seeing your methods, it looks like you will need to make that EmailDAL.SendEmail() method of yours async. To do that you could do something like the following:

```
public async Task<string> SendEmailAsync(string toMail, string mailSubject, string Message) {

    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(SMTP);
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(MailAddress);
    mail.To.Add(toMail);
    mail.Subject = mailSubject;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Body = "<p style='line-height: 30px;'>" + Message + "</p>";
    SmtpServer.Port = Port;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailAddress, Pwd);
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = ssl;
    try {
        await SmtpServer.SendAsync(mail);
        return "Send Successfully";
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Then, `btn_ok()` might look like:

```
protected async void btn_ok(object sender, EventArgs e) {

try { 
    //**Job 1:**
    CommonCls com = new CommonCls();
    com.SaveRecord(**Parameter Values**);

    //Note :after save this, it must exit from this function and update Message to web Application Screen 

    //**Job 2** 
    EmailDAL em = new EmailDAL();
    .....
    .....

    try {
        await em.SendEmailAsync(PTEmail, "Appointment Rescheduled ", "Dear " + PTName + "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Appointment with " + PName + " referred by " + GPName + "  has been rescheduled " + Stime + ". <br> with Regards <br> <b>" + GPName + "</b>" + axolbl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex.ToString()); }
        try {
            await em.SendEmailAsync(PEmail, "Appointment Rescheduled ", "Dear " + PName + "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Appointment for  " + PTName + "(" + PTCode + ")  referred by " + GPName + " has been rescheduled " + Stime + ".  <br> with Regards <br> <b>" + GPName + "</b>" + axolbl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex.ToString()); }
        try {
            await em.SendEmailAsync(GPEmail, "Appointment Rescheduled ", "Dear " + GPName + "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Appointment for " + PTName + "(" + PTCode + ")  with " + PName + "  has been rescheduled " + Stime + ". <br> with Regards <br>  " + axolbl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex.ToString()); }   
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Check out the link below to read more about using the `SmtpClient.SendAsync` method and how to receive updates when the email has finished transmitting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx

Now we still need to see what `CommonCls.SaveRecord()` looks like to make that one async.

**Original Answer
You may want to try using `Task.WhenAny()` along with `async` and `await`. It will return as soon as a single job finishes but then it will still continue to let the second job finish. Although I cannot tell what version of .NET you are working with.

Below is an MSDN article about it. Hope this helps:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx

Comment: Hi i am using 4.0... But I cannot understand the code  from this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx  Please Answer from my Post.

Comment: Are your `.SaveRecord()` and `SendEmail()` methods async? And are they returning a `Task<T>`?

Comment: What do those two methods look like? Can you post their code?

Comment: Check out my new edit. Still need your `.SaveRecord()` code to see how to make that one async.

Comment: Hello sir...   Error  Comes like Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? You may need to increase it to .Net 4.5.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your helping.. Sorry i could not able to reply due to my another work.. I refer your code and test it in DotNet 4.5. Its working fine.. But It take Own time. No use for async method... :(